# ionic cordova - white page when adding 'ngCordova'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

When I adding 'ngCordova' to app.js I am getting a white page.
code:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova','app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.directives','app.services'])
```

I included the cordova.js in index.html:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

What i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

In console, have you an error or a warning?

Check your path to be correct. Where have you installed cordova?

An example:

In my case i have:

```
 <script src="lib/ng-cordova-0.1.17-alpha/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

I give the full path.

Do you give the correct path?

You can use the following steps:

```
$ bower install ngCordova
```

Include ng-cordova.js or ng-cordova.min.js in your index.html file before cordova.js and after your AngularJS / Ionic file (since ngCordova depends on AngularJS).

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Then, include ngCordova as a dependency in your angular module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```

Comment: what is ng-cordova.js?

Comment: I have only <script src="cordova.js"></script>

Comment: I edit my answer.Plese check it out.please let me know if this solve your problem.